# New Jobs page shows "Create a Developer CV" on SO profile when I already have one

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I've opt'd into the new Jobs feature. However, I now have a giant "Create a developer CV" on my SO profile. I already *have* a CV. The button itself, and the "Edit CV" 'tab' both take me to my CV.

[image: Create CV]

This button should be either removed or renamed if the CV already exists.

Comment: Is this button really new? I think that I had it on my profile for at least a couple of months. It always correctly linked to my careers CV.

Comment: If I remember correctly I just had to enable it in my SO profile settings.

Comment: No. If you didn't have a profile linked you had a "Discover Stack Overflow Careers" button. If you did, you had the option of showing or hiding the button. In this case, the button *appears* to be the same of the "Discover..." link. Since I already have such a profile, I am requesting it be renamed appropriately. I don't need to create one.

Comment: @Andy Yeah.... that should say View My Developer CV once you've been linked. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Andy Def a bug, on the list of things to fix before it comes out of beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report, Andy. This should be fixed now.

We had a couple different spots where we were keeping the "has a cv" bit in the database that got out of sync. We cleaned those up and things should be mo' bettah now.